Azure Automation Custom Module not Exporting Commands
I am trying to use a custom PowerShell module in an Azure Automation account.
I have prepared the module and tested it locally. It is loaded and the commands can be used.

However, when I pack and upload my module to Azure Automation it always imports the module without exporting the commands although the path is existing and the functions should be available.

My module consists of dedicated files for each functions located in the 'functions' folder of the module. I am using the following approach to load the functions via my .psm1 file:
$functions = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\functions\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

foreach ($import in @($functions)) {
    try {
        . $import.Fullname -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.Fullname): $_" -ErrorAction Continue
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function $functions.Basename

My .psd1 is created from a template:
 
#...
RootModule        = 'MHZ.Developer.psm1
#...
 FunctionsToExport = '*'
    CmdletsToExport   = '*'
    VariablesToExport = '*'
    AliasesToExport   = @()
#...

I tried commenting the values out, writing explicit function names or switching between wildcard and empty array without luck. According to blogs I read it also does not really matter since my .psm1 exports the members. Its only relevant for auto loading the cmdlets which I don't really mind.
Shouldn't that work in Azure Automation the same way it works locally or am I overseeing something?

UPDATE
My zip folder structure looks as followed:
MHZ.Developer.zip
├── MHZ.Developer.psd1
├── MHZ.Developer.psm1
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── Get-FooBaa.ps1

Creating another folder with the module name in the zip does not make a difference. After uploading the module is always available under path C:\usr\src\PSModules\MHZ.Developer\MHZ.Developer.psm1
Changing the FunctionsToExport to something like:
FunctionsToExport = @(
'Get-Function1',
'Get-Function2',
'Get-Function3'
)

Does not make a difference either.

You're uploading the module to the AA as a zip file right? If so, can you add the module tree structure to your question? Or if you have it in a GitHub repo please share the link

@SantiagoSquarzon correct I am packaging a zip file which I upload with Terraform. Structure is as followed:
MHZ.Developer.zip
├── MHZ.Developer.psd1
├── MHZ.Developer.psm1
├── functions
│   ├── Get-FooBaa.ps1

Structure seems right but I believe the zip needs a folder with the module name then below it you put your psm1 and psd1 etc: MHZ.Developer.zip -> MHZ.Developer -> MHZ.Developer.psd1 & MHZ.Developer.psd1, functions, etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#version-folder for more info. Also, the Export-ModuleMember line is not needed, just remove it.

@jdweng not sure what you meant. I am not trying to connect to servers or running the module on one.

@SantiagoSquarzon I was thinking about that but the structure after unpacking is correct on the Automation Account: ....\PSModules\MHZ.Developer\functions I can try with a subfolder but it seemed unnecessary to me.

I think the structure isnt the problem but its worth trying nonetheless. I think the issue is the Export-ModuleMember line. Also in FunctionsToExport I would probably use FunctionsToExport = @('Get-FooBaa')

@SantiagoSquarzon yeah regardless of the structure the module path in the account is shown as "C:\usr\src\PSModules\MHZ.Developer\MHZ.Developer.psm1" so I guess that seems alright. What do you think is the issue with Export-ModuleMember? I think I tried to set FunctionsToExport already but with a different syntax. This seemed  not the issue either.

I assume you're deleting the module before re uploading it right? Export-ModuleMember is just not needed if using a psd1

@SantiagoSquarzon you meant on the Automation Account? Yes, its not needed though as it updates either way but I also tried deleting it before uploading again. FuctionsToExport did not make a difference and I believe Export-ModuleMember is needed to populate the functions as they are in a subdirectory. At least that's what I saw wiedely recommended at it does not work without locally either. So if not with that command there needs to be something else to populate the functions.

That's incorrect. Any function loaded by the psm1 including dot sourced functions will be part of the exported commands. Not sure where you saw that recommendation but it is clearly incorrect. A very simple example: https://i.imgur.com/XpTT2G2.png

@SantiagoSquarzon I read it multiple times on stackoverflow and it's referenced in this blog : https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Building-A-PowerShell-Module/. If you reverse engineer some psmodules you will see it's even used in quite a lot of Microsoft developed modules. It's my first module but that's how I got to it.

I'm aware there are several blogs implying that it is needed but it is not, empiric evidence
proves it. The reason I'm guessing that the issue could be the Export-ModuleMember line is because you're exporting -Function $functions.Basename, which would be fine as long as in your functions folder you had a ps1 file per each function with a file base name that matches exactly the function name (i.e.: Get-GraphObject.ps1, Get-SpoSite.ps1, ...)

Another thing that can help you troubleshoot is using Import-Module MHZ.Developer -Force -Verbose in your runbook, verbose message can help you understand what is actually getting imported

@SantiagoSquarzon that is exactly my use case. A file per function which is exactly named as each which I guess is the reason why it works locally. There must be something with the paths working differently in Azure. Will try the Verbose mode though. Thank you for the suggestion.

Try uploading the module using the hierarchy shown in the doc, ModuleName -> 1.0.1 -> psm1 & psd1, functions, etc also update the version in the psd1. I have personally only uploaded modules to AA when I need to upload a .dll and never use the module itself, just the assembly so I haven't found issues with it but I wouldn't be surprised if it was bugged

@SantiagoSquarzon you are right, indeed no bug but I thought it might be something wrong with the way I upload with Terraform and I found it. Its actually recreating the zip but the file is not triggering to update the Azure Storage Account Blob. I fixed that now and will test with removing Export-ModuleMember and set `FunctionsToExport' .

@SantiagoSquarzon I was able to fix it with you remarks. Have updated my post accordingly. Thank you very much.

glad it helped but you should post the solution as an answer instead of as an edit to your question ;) you can also accept your own answer so it can help others in the future

@SantiagoSquarzon thanks for the suggestion. It's my first post. Will do so.

@SantiagoSquarzon I actually lack the reputation to post answer as this is my first post. Maybe you can?

I've upvoted your question, I think that gives you enough privilege to self-answer. Try again https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

np! remember to click the tick checkbox to accept the answer, I think you need to wait 48hs tho

Solution
By the help of the comments I could find the solution and answer my own question.
Despite working locally I had to remove Export-ModuleMember from my .psm1 so it looks like this:
$functions = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\functions\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

foreach ($import in @($functions)) {
    try {
        . $import.Fullname -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.Fullname): $_" -ErrorAction Continue
    }
}

and set FunctionsToExport in my .psd1 to all functions that should be available like this:
   FunctionsToExport = @(
        'Get-Function1',
        'Get-Function2',
        'Get-Function3'
    )

to make the module working in Azure Automation.

I'm having the same exact problem. I had the Export-ModuleMember in my psm1 file and have FunctionsToExport set to "*". The functions are being exported locally but when I upload to AA, nothing is exported. This was working for several years now. I updated one function earlier and when I try uploading to AA to update the module, it now doesn't export any of the functions.
I tried removing Export-ModuleMmeber from my psm1 file as suggested in this thr
